# Find the RIP instruction pointer in x64 MSVC?

Tags: c, x86-64, masm

Trying to find the runtime memory address of this instruction in the code below

```
int here = 42;
```

Is this a correct approach and are there other methods?

In the x64 version of the Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) compiler, the RIP register (also known as the "instruction pointer register") is a 64-bit register that holds the memory address of the next instruction to be executed.

https://godbolt.org/z/f8WzGMqsE

I think godbolt uses a debug build as ***int here = 42;*** has not been optimized out.

[image: rip]

```
#include <stdio.h>

void* RIP = NULL;

__declspec(noinline) void GetRIP(void)
{
    // RIP is the instruction pointer register on a 64-bit platform.
    RIP = _ReturnAddress();
}

int main(void)
{
    GetRIP();
    
    // Find the runtime memory address of this instruction.
    int here = 42;

    printf("RIP = %p\n", RIP);
    
    return 0;
}
```

In MASM x64, the RIP is found using this technique

```
option casemap:none

extrn printf:proc

.data
     szRIP db 'RIP = %p',0ah,0

.code

main proc
     call    _here
_here:
     pop     rax
     ; rax now holds the RIP.
     mov     rdx,rax 
     mov     rcx,offset szRIP
     sub     rsp,20h
     call    printf
     add     rsp,20h

     ret
main endp

end
```

Comment: That `call/pop` trick is bit old-fashioned, in x64 a RIP-relative `lea` is a more direct way to get `rip` into a GPR (that doesn't do you much good in C though)

Comment: "Is this a correct approach and are there other methods?" There really is no "correct" method because the compiler is not required to initialize the variable exactly at the point you write it in the code. Optimizations are very likely to do things like split the variable, preinitialize the variable, inline the variable, or even remove the variable outright.